# How to declare a static HashMap in ExtJS?

Tags: web, extjs, data-structures, hashmap

**Requirement:**

Need to use HashMap to store particular values. 
For the first time, the values are set to the HashMap and after screen refresh or on navigation and back to that same screen, **need to retain values in the HashMap in the UI itself** without making a backend/DB call.

What is the best way to declare and make use of this HashMap so that it is **initialized only once** but retains added values on screen refresh and navigation ?

How do we ***declare*** and ***initialize*** this HashMap as a **static variable** ?

Comment: which ExtJS version are you using?

Comment: ExtJS version is 5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can partially achieve it using an ExtJS Store with LocalStorage Proxy.
Local Storage allows you to store data in browser space. On page reload the data will be persistence (Only in the same user profile in the browser).

This store data will not be available in another browser. If you are looking for user-specific caching of HTTP responses that work across browser it will have to be on the server side.

**Here is POC implementation for same browser and same user profile:**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('twitter', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['id', 'name'],
            proxy: {
                type: 'localstorage',
                id: 'twitter-Searches'
            }
        });

        //our Store automatically picks up the LocalStorageProxy defined on the Search model
        var store = new Ext.data.Store({
            model: "twitter"
        });

        //loads any existing Search data from localStorage
        store.load();

        console.log(store);

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'grid',
                store: store,
                id: 'gridId',
                columns: [{
                    text: 'id',
                    flex: 1,
                    dataIndex: 'id'
                }, {
                    text: 'name',
                    flex: 1,
                    dataIndex: 'name'
                }],
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Add new record',
                    handler: function () {
                        var grid = Ext.getCmp("gridId");
                        var record = {
                            //id: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
                            name: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
                        };

                        store.add(record);
                        store.sync();
                    }
                }, {
                    text: "Clear all",
                    handler: function () {
                        var grid = Ext.getCmp("gridId");
                        store.removeAll();
                        store.sync();

                    }
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

**Here is fiddle for same:** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2cgt

In Fiddle, on reloading the fiddle, the data is being picked up from local storage.

Comment: Yes, this solution works partially. But, if i load the same screen in different browser or system, it would no longer be applicable. Thank you for your help though, it solves an altogether different problem that I am facing currently.